# Does the Mitel 3300 support direct SIP Trunking?

Tags: sip, mitel

We have a Mitel 3300 PBX and we're looking to replace our PRI and BRI lines with SIP Trunking. I've seen that the 3300 supports SIP, but does it support direct SIP from a prospective ISP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.mitel.com/resources/242_9113-Mitel3300ControllersDataSheet.pdf

Looks like it supports both SIP endpoints and SIP trunks. (which would be SIP from an ISP, yes)